# I want to add 5 images to the left side and 4 to the right by clicking the button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem in my code i want to add images by clicking the button , but the browser appears empty, could any one help me to solve this code

```js
function generateFaces(){
    var numberFaces = 5;
    while(numberFaces!=0){
        var faceLeft = Math.random() * 400;
        var faceTop = Math.random() * 400;
        var faceBottom = Math.random() * 400;
        var faceRight = Math.random() * 400;
        var theFaces = document.createElement("img");
        theFaces.setAttribute("src","http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png");
        theFaces.style.position="absolute";
        theFaces.style.left=faceLeft+'px';
        theFaces.style.right=faceLeft+'px';
        theFaces.style.top=faceTop+'px';
        theFaces.style.bottom = faceTop+'px';
        theFaces.setAttribute("alt", "Flower");
        document.getElementById("leftSide").appendChild(theFaces);
        var leftSidee = document.getElementById("leftSide");
        var rightSidee = leftSidee.cloneNode(true);
        document.getElementById("rightSide").appendChild(rightSidee);
        numberFaces = numberFaces-1;
    }
    var theParent = document.getElementById("rightSide");
    theParent.removeChild(theParent.lastChild);
}
```

```html
<body id="bodyid" >
    <h2> Matching Game </h2>
    <p> Click on the extra smiling face on the left </p>
    <div id="leftSide"> </div>
    <div id="rightSide"> </div>
    <button onclick="generateFaces()"> Click here to add faces </button> 
</body>
```

Comment: Please also show the corresponding part of the HTML related to the problem?

Comment: This is my Html code '<body id="bodyid" >
    <h2> Matching Game </h2>
    <p> Click on the extra smiling face on the left </p>
    <div id="leftSide">
    </div>
    <div id="rightSide">
    </div>
    <button onclick="generateFaces()"> Click here to add faces </button>
    </body>'

Comment: Not post as a comment, click 'edit' and update your post.

Comment: In the stack snippet, images are added to the DOM. What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Yes you are right but still doesn't work in my Dreamweaver and my browser

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate the meaning 'doesn't work' and what you are expecting your code to be behaviour. Your code generated 5 images within the `<div id="leftSide"> . . </div>` and clone the entire '<div id="leftSide>..</div>' block together with the images within the `<div id="rightSide"> .. </div>` 4 times, which is exactly what you code asking to do. Also you don't have any grid system (at least not shown), so how do you expect certain element staying at left, and others stay at right?